# .NET Core build contains dll files I dont use (Azure DevOps)

Tags: asp.net-core, dll, azure-devops

I have a small application that builds on Azure DevOps as a framework-dependent deployment and is released to a server. 
And I'm trying to figure out why have a bunch oh .dll files I dont need/use in my zip file.

Example of files:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll
Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.dll
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll
SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll
+ alot more
```

Where can I find the connections to these dependencies and remove them?

Comment: Are they referenced as NuGet packages?

Comment: I found the issue. A nuget package was referring to AspNetCore.All instead of App as the rest of solution. It then added some dlls I didn't need.